# SQL Cast / Conversion Varchar to Date

Tags: sql, date, varchar, dbeaver

I'm trying to convert a "date" column saved as varchar with the following format : 'March 15, 2014' into a date type so that I can then order the entries by date in the next step.

So far I've tried this :

`` select cast( `date` as date)  from Kampf ``

which yields the result "Incorrect datetime value: 'March 15, 2014'"

as well as

`` select CONVERT(date, `date`, 101)  from Kampf ``

which just gives me this syntax error

"SQL-Fehler [1064] [42000]: (conn=103554) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
(conn=103554) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
(conn=103554) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
LIMIT 0, 200' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, 101)  from Kampf
LIMIT 0, 200' at line 1
"

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE` function in MariaDB. Always refer to the documentation corresponding to your RDBMS instead of first result in Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB, you would use `str_to_date()`:

```
select str_to_date('March 15, 2014', '%M %d, %Y')
```

The use of `convert()` that you are attempting is SQL Server-specific syntax.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I did not know about the SQL Server-specific syntax and will keep that in mind for the future.